# is there an R function for finding distance from the mean by SD

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to categorise observations according to their distance from the mean. The following works:

```
cars <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(mean_disp = mean(disp)) %>%
  mutate(sd_disp = sd(disp)) %>%
  mutate(sd1_top = mean_disp + sd_disp) %>%
  mutate(sd1_bot = mean_disp - sd_disp) %>%
  mutate(sd1 = case_when(disp > sd1_top | disp < sd1_bot ~ TRUE))
```

but it's awkward as I need to find several categories, 1... 4 SD from the mean. I have sought but not found a better solution, perhaps along the lines of the `dplyr::ntile()` function.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a simple function for it. `...` means that you can add `na.rm = TRUE` as necessary.

```
outside_sd <- function(x, sd_range, ...) {
  m <- mean(x, ...)
  sd <- sd(x, ...)
  x > (m + sd * sd_range) | x < (m - sd * sd_range)
}

cars <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(
    sd1 = outside_sd(disp, 1),
    sd2 = outside_sd(disp, 2),
    sd3 = outside_sd(disp, 3),
    sd4 = outside_sd(disp, 4)
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

The `scale` function converts to z-scores which gives you the number of standard deviations:

```
z <- scale(mtcars$disp)
head(z)
#             [,1]
# [1,] -0.57061982
# [2,] -0.57061982
# [3,] -0.99018209
# [4,]  0.22009369
# [5,]  1.04308123
# [6,] -0.04616698
```

Then you need to be specific about what 1 standard deviation means, 1 to <2, .5 to 5, ignoring +/- standard deviations?

```
table(as.integer(z))
# 
# -1  0  1 
#  5 21  6 
table(floor(z))
# 
# -2 -1  0  1 
#  5 12  9  6 
table(round(z))
# 
# -1  0  1  2 
# 16  5  8  3 
table(round(abs(z)))
# 
#  0  1  2 
#  5 24  3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` approach -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

mtcars1 <- mtcars %>% mutate(mean_disp = mean(disp), sd_disp = sd(disp))


bind_cols(mtcars1, map_dfc(1:4, ~mtcars1 %>%
      mutate(sd1_top = mean_disp + .x * sd_disp, 
             sd1_bot = mean_disp - .x * sd_disp, 
             !!paste0('sd', .x) := case_when(disp > sd1_top | disp < sd1_bot ~ TRUE)) %>%
      select(paste0('sd', .x))))
```